# Site not opening in Opera Mini..working in all other browsers

Tags: asp.net, opera-mini

I have an asp.net site which is not opening in *Opera Mini*..but it is working in all other browsers...giving **`error as server timed out`**..pls check the link `**http://203.122.58.93**`

Thanks in advance...!!

Comment: is anyone there ? plz help

Answer (score 1):

Just few [facts](http://www.opera.com/ru/help/mini/faq):

- `Opera Mini` use transcoder servers.
- When you request a page in `Opera Mini`, the request is sent to the `Opera Mini` server that then downloads the page from the web. The server then wraps up your page up in a neat little compressed package (we call the format [OBML](http://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-binary-markup-language/)), and sends it back to your phone at the speed of ninjas with jetpacks.
- Opera Mini has default config with 30 secs limit for loading data from your server. Just write `config:` in your address bar and check it.

So, I think that you site can be to large for your mobile internet or your mobile operator has low internet connection quality/speed and you don't send data before the 30 secs limit ends. You can increase it in your local config and test again.

Why I think what this is the answer? Because my Opera Mini on Android and using Wifi open *
`http://203.122.58.93` very quickly :)